# JavaScript Timer Issues - Counts down in 2 Second Intervals & Sound doesn't play

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, raspberry-pi, countdown

I'm making a countdown timer using a mixture of JavaScript, Jquery and PHP for a classroom timer. It is run off a raspberry pi connected to an LG TV. There are a few unusual errors when I run my code which... appear some but not all of the time.

Here is my code...

```
$("#start").click(function(){
    $("#start").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#start").html("Resume");
    $("#stop").removeAttr("disabled",null);
    $("#storage").html("start");
    dec();
})

var file = document.getElementById("alert"); 



var time = prompt("Please specify the time in minutes:");
var minutes = time - 1;
var secs = 59;
var displayMins = minutes;


$("#stop").click(function(){
    $("#stop").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#start").removeAttr("disabled",null);
    $("#storage").html("stop");
})

$("#reset").click(function(){
    $("#stop").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#start").removeAttr("disabled",null);
    $("#storage").html("reset");
   dec();
})


function dec() {
    if($("#storage").html() != "stop" && $("#storage").html() != "reset" ){



    if(secs <= 0){
       secs = 59;
        displayMins = displayMins - 1;
    }
    if(displayMins < 10){
        $("#timer").html("0" + displayMins + ":" + secs);
    } 
    if(secs < 10){
        $("#timer").html(displayMins + ":" + "0" + secs);
    }
    if(secs < 10 && displayMins < 10){
        $("#timer").html("0" + displayMins + ":" + "0" + secs);
    }
    if(secs > 10 && displayMins > 10){
        $("#timer").html(displayMins + ":" + secs);
    }
    secs = secs - 1;
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(secs >= 1 && displayMins >= 0){
          dec();  
        } else if(secs == 0 && displayMins == 0){
            var audio = new Audio('airhorn.mp3');
            audio.play();
            $("#timer").html("00:00");
            $("#timer").css("color", "red");

        }

    }, 1000);
} else if($("#storage").html() == "reset"){
    $("#start").removeAttr("disabled",null);
    $("#start").html("Start");
    $("#stop").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    secs = 59;
    displayMins = minutes;
     $("#timer").html("00:00");

    $("#timer").css("color", "white");
}
```

}

Here is my PHP code...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="style/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Mr. George's Timer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/reload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Mr. George's Timer
    </h1>
    <div id="timer">
        00:00
    </div>

    <button id="start" onclick="dec();">Start</button>
     <button id="stop" disabled="disabled">Stop</button>
     <button id="reset">Reset</button>
     <br /><br />
     <audio id="alert">
      <source src="airhorn.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" id="alert">
    </audio>
     <!-- <select name="type" id="timeSelector">
             <option value="5">5min</option>
            <option value="10">10 min</option>
            <option value="15">15 min</option>
            <option value="20">20 min</option>
            <option value="25">25 min</option>
            <option value="30">30 min</option>
            <option value="35">35 min</option>
            <option value="40">40 min</option>
            <option value="45">45 min</option>
            <option value="50">50 min</option>
            <option value="55">55 min</option>
            <option value="60">60 min</option>
     </select> !-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/watch.js"></script>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label id="storage">storage</label>
    <label id="timestorage">5</label>
</body>
```

**My Errors**

1. When I run the program it counts down in two second intervals, this occurs most but not all of the time.
2. When I run the program with five minutes on the timer it always stops at "4:01".
3. When the countdown timer gets to zero the "airhorn.mp3" sound file doesn't play.

If you need any more details please comment and I will respond as soon as possible.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: please, provide errors messages.

Comment: You're asking two different questions. You'll get more answers if you separate them.